# ¿Cómo insertar/modificar código HTML desde código PHP?

Tags: php, html, html-select

¿Es posible insertar/modificar código de fichero HTML desde otro fichero externo de código PHP? Tengo entendido que desde un fichero externo JavaScript si es posible llamando a una función desde HTML, pero en mi caso me interesa hacerlo en PHP. En concreto lo que quiero modificar es el 'select' id = 'JugadoresCuadro' añadiendo un 'option' pero desde otro fichero PHP. Pienso que algún modo habrá, de hecho me ha funcionado sin añadirlo al 'select', es decir, añadiendo solo un 'option' al fichero. Pero en el momento en que quiero añadir el 'option' al 'select' con 'select'.appendChild('option') me salta error.

Perdonad mi ignorancia pero soy bastante novato en programación web. Agradecería mucho si alguien sabe como solucionarlo, gracias de antemano.

A continuación pongo los códigos resumidos.

Este es mi código miequipo.html:

```
<html>
   <head>
       <?php include("insertarequipo.php");
       insertarequipo();
       ?>
   </head>

   <body>
       <select multiple id= "JugadoresCuadro">
       </select>
   </body>
</html>
```

y el codigo insertarequipo.php:

```
<?php
function insertarequipo() {
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $sel = $dom->getElementById('JugadoresCuadro');
    $opt = $dom->createElement('option', "Pablo");
    $opt->setAttribute("id", "jugador1");

    $dom->appendChild($opt); //Esto corre bien, pero no lo inserta en el select
    echo $dom->saveHTML();

    //$selopt = $sel->appendChild($opt); //Esto me da error, que es como creía que era
    //$dom->appendChild($selopt);
    //echo $dom->saveHTML();
}
?>
```

Comment: `$dom` es un documento vacío, `$sel->appendChild` da error por que no lo encuentra. si queres modificar el select añadiendo options dentro del mismo archivo directamente lo haces en el select, `DOMDocument` lo podes usar para crear un html desde cero o para cargar y modificar otro html con [`$dom->loadHTMLFile()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php)

Comment: Desde PHP necesitas usar `require` o `include`, para poner el otro archivo PHP en contexto y luego poder usar su contenido (si éste existe en una variable, función, clase, etc). Supongo que hablas de otro archivo con extensión `.php`. Si fuese un archivo de texto: `.html`, `.css`, `.txt`, etc. entonces puedes usar `file_get_contents()` . De todos modos la pregunta no es clara, no veo en qué parte quieres usar lo que hay en el otro archivo  ¿?

Comment: Gracias  alo Malbarez, me sirvió. También tuve que añadir un $dom->saveHTMLFile("miequipo.html") ya que mi intención era modificar el fichero "miequipo.html".